# Custom Single Template

Tags: customization, single

OK. This has probably been asked quite a few times, but here it is again. Everything I find on the web is on how to create a custom template for category, which I don't want, and the rest doesn't work. 
I want to create a custom template for single post, to have plain and simple selection of templates available. One of the blog posts said

> locate the single.php and make a copy and call it something like single-newspost.php

Which I did. And then, I should make a php statement like this one

```
<?php
/*
Single Post Template:News Post
*/
?>
```

Which I also did. But it didn't work. My guess is- there must also be something in the functions.php , but my knowledge is very limited.

Comment: `single-newspost.php` is the template for the _custom post type_ `newspost`, which, I guess, you don't have. Edit the existing `single.php` if you don't use custom post types. Make a backup copy of the template first.

Answer (score 0):

In which part it didn't work? is there any error code ?

dont forget to select your new template in post you want. 
[image]

Comment: There is simply no template selection. No errors either

Comment: What about screen option on post page ? is post attributes checked ? you may switch to default theme to see if it's caused by theme / plugin function or not.

Answer (score 0):

Correct header format is:

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: News Post
 * Template Post Type: post
 */
?>
```

Make sure you place this at the top of the file, WordPress only reads a limited number of characters when checking if a template file has a header.